# Spring @Transactional: Rollback information reported but not actually performed

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, testing, junit

I have annotated my test classes as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/context-aspects.xml"})
@Transactional
public class MyTest {

}
```

However, when executing tests, the test database is suddenly filled with values, although @Transactional is enabled and I can read the following in the log:

```
INFO: Began transaction (4): transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager@669aa3f3]; rollback [true]
07.04.2011 23:57:33 org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener endTransaction
INFO: Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context ...
```

Any ideas why the actual rollback after the test case is not performed?

**Update:** If I am using HSQLDB, I don't have these problems - so is it a problem of mysql?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: In case of an MySQL, which type do you use: MyISAM, or InnoDB?

Comment: I am using MySQL InnoDB. In another project it works with the same database, but I am unable to figure out where the differences in the configurations are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update: If I am using HSQLDB, I don't have these problems - so is it a problem of mysql?

Yes you are right.

Check that you use the right dialect (when using Hibernate: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect), and may you should monitor the statements that been send to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I could finally solve the problem. Hibernate was generating MyISAM tables which apparently have no Transaction support. This was due to a wrong hibernate dialect configured. I used
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect, but org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect is required.